# Context reaction : Exclude specific block?

Tags: 6, blocks

I've got a website with 3 large contexts :
- internet
- intranet
- shop

These 3 contexts are "tight" (sorry about my english, I think this is the word).

My Block UI (admin/build/block) provides to every pages 2 blocks in my website first sidebar.

In my Shop context, I've got a specific header, footer, and about 6 blocks in the first sidebar.
The conditions are quite simples : Paths only.
- shop/*
- cart/*
and some others.

My node-product pages are in my Shop context conditions, and that's fine. (I don't want my users to lose the shop header, shop menu, shop footer and so on...) when they are on a product page.

**Now, what I would like to do is to exclude 3 of my 6 side blocks on my node-product pages.**

So I was thinking... What if we had an "Exclude Blocks" Reaction in context ?
That is exactly what I need to do what I'm expecting.

I tried to adjust visibility settings in block UI, but it seems that context UI overrides it...

Shall I duplicate my Shop context to have a Shop-product one ? Is that clean ?
I mean... All this context definition is correct, and I only want to exclude 3 blocks... Isn't that overkill to duplicate all my settings ?

Any Ideas ?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be overkill to duplicate the context if it works ;)

Context is often used with [Delta](http://drupal.org/project/delta) to provide layout and theme adjustments for internal pages. After setting up a few Delta layouts you will be able to specify a Context/Delta reaction and switch the applied Delta template for your Shop-product page.

[Take a look at this decent Delta+Context tutorial.](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/control-your-drupal-page-layout-context-and-delta) Good luck!

EDIT: If you're not already committed to a theme, the Omega theme has some incredible integration with Context/Delta - [intro tutorial here](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/tmccullough/2013/03/05/drupal-7-and-omega-part-2-delta-and-context-modules).

Comment: I forgot to say explicitly that I was on D6. I will try to duplicate my context

Comment: Oops, sorry... missed the '6' tag.